# how to create offline maps for android phone using OL3?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I am trying to create a mapping application for android phone (using Openlayers-3). I have a requirement that I need to save map in my phone because there might not be internet to display the map in phone.

I can download OSM map from internet. How can I use OSM map offline in my application?

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

AJ

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you want to achieve? Simple map viewing? Geocoding? Routing? Anyway, this question has already been answered various times.

Comment: I want to use offline maps for simple map viewing, and locating my coordinates with other simple functionalities. I have to use Openlayers3 for this application. I can use any map as background. The only requirement is that it has to be offline. I didn't find the answer that I need in this forum that is why I am posting the question. I hope you can give me general idea how to do this.

Comment: What geographic area are we talking about? What zoom levels? It won't be possible to store tiles for the whole world and each zoom level offline on your phone.

Comment: I am trying to download the Map of Nepal. I know that I can't store the map of whole world. I just want map of Nepal. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @A-J consider accepting the answer given so the question won't remain opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small regions you can pre-render all required [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) using [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive), [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill) or a similar application. Also take a look at the various [rendering softwares for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering).

For larger regions consider using [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) instead of raster tiles. You can render them using [mapsforge](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapsforge).

Comment: what should I do after rendering the map? how should I use it in my application? how to create OL3 application for android?

Comment: Just specify the path to your local tiles as tile source in OpenLayers, that's all. You don't need to create an "application", a simple HTML page plus the OpenLayers JS library will suffice. Take a look at the OL examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will work on it during the weekend and will post my status next week. Thanks again mate.